# Стоит ли заменить подход std:thread на std::async?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, асинхронность, многоагентная-система

В проекте (многоагентная система для работы с потоком разнотиповых данных в реальном времени) используется многопоточность из стандартной библиотеки C++, а именно подход на основе потоков `std::thread`.

Функционал каждого агента исполняется в отдельном потоке. Учитывая соотношение между количеством агентов и характеристиками железа, на котором работает эта система - такое разделение (на потоки) имеет логический характер, а не производительный (это будет решаться позже).

Прочитал недавно про подход на основе задач `std::async`.

Вопросы:

1. Может ли мне дать какое-то преимущество этот подход?
2. И какие сложности могут возникнуть в рамках описанной системы?
3. Где прочитать про эту технологию? Я смотрел только пару обзорных статей.

Comment: Почитать про новый стандарт можно в книге: "The C++ Stardard Library. Second edition. Nicolai M. Josuttis"
Преимущества может дать, если потоки  быстро создаются и закрываются. std::async может использовать уже ранее созданный и незанятый поток для выполнения очередной задачи. В то время как std::thread создаст новый поток.

Comment: Продолжайте использовать `std::thread`, `std::async` это мертворождённая функция, от которой крайне мало проку.

Comment: @ixSci в чем мертворожденность заключается?

Comment: В C#, например, схожая концепция (`async`/`await`) очень хорошо взлетела, не в последнюю очередь за счёт поддержки со стороны стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @alexolut, в бесполезности этой функции. Она должна была быть упразднена, но у комитета духу не хватило признать ошибку и удалить её. Вместо этого они начала вставлять [костыли](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3773.pdf). Пока в языке нет нормальных задач (task) и обязательства исполнять оные в пуле потоков, подобной функции просто нет места.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эффективность `std::async` сильно зависит от реализации. В старых версиях gcc, например, `std::async` вообще всегда работает в том же потоке, где вызывается `future.get()`, несмотря на флаг `launch_async`. Но даже если реализация хорошая, в лучшем случае `std::async` будет отправлять задачу в обычный пул потоков. В этом случае проще взять сразу готовый пул потоков и работать с ним, тем более есть пулы потоков с поддержкой `std::future`, что делает их интерфейс похожим на `std::async`. Одна из реализаций есть [тут](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool).

Возможно, для вашей задачи будет удобно использовать в качестве пула потоков `boost::asio`, поскольку помимо обычных возможностей пула потоков там есть таймеры и асинхронный ввод-вывод (ради чего библиотека и создавалась).